# Changed file ownership to root but original user can still edit the file?

Tags: linux, cpanel, file-permissions, chmod, chown

I ran the following commands:

```
chown root:root file.php
chmod 0644 file.php
```

Settings appear to have been applied when typing `ls -l`:

`-rw-r--r--  1 root root 310 Jul 26 01:25 file.php`

However, the original user can still edit the file via Cpanel File Manager and upon saving, the file ownership went back to the original user. E.g.,

`-rw-r--r--  1 orig_user orig_user 310 Jul 26 01:25 file.php`

How do I prevent the user from editing files already owned by root?

Comment: What's the account that your web server is running under?

Comment: Looks like I was incorrect :P
https://serverfault.com/questions/648573/linux-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-protect-a-file-from-being-deleted-even-by-root

Comment: @merlin2011 Yeah! `chattr +i` worked like a boss

Comment: The original user probably has write permission on the directory, and Cpanel File Manager is probably removing the link to the file that is owned by root and replacing it with a link to a file that is owned by the original user.

Comment: Try `ls -i` to see if the file the link `file.php` references is changing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`chattr`](https://serverfault.com/a/648574/107789) on the file to make it immutable.

```
sudo chattr +i file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If the editor uses "erase old file + write new file" instead of "modify existing file", this works perfect. If so, the permissions on the containing directory must be changed to prevent a user from erasing the file.

Removing a file did not depend on the permission of the file!

Try it out in a shell:

```
> touch bla
> chmod 000 bla
> sudo chown root:root bla
> rm bla
... maybe a warning ...
```

but the file will be erased!

As this `chown` and `chmod` did not help for the file, but for the containing directory.

On filesystems like ext2, ext3 and most common newer ones you can use `chattr` to protect with more attributes.

```
> sudo chattr +i bla 
> lsattr bla
```

From the `chattr` man page:

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Comment: But file owner is root, how cpanel can remove it, unless cpanel is opened with root privileges

Comment: As said: I can remove a file even if I have no permission to change the file. You only can set read/write/execute permissions on the file itself. If you want to erase it, you do modify the directory which contains the file. The file itself is not modified. Sounds strange, but works perfect. If you use a shell to check it, you maybe get a warning that you want to erase a write protected file. But you still can do it by ignoring the warning. And this is only a convenience warning ;)